# What was Tim's last message?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

My friend Tim was an electrical enthusiast and he kept experimenting on new things. A few days back he called me for help. He wanted me to meet him as fast as I could. He sounded quite terrified. As I went down to his house. I noticed the door was smashed in half. As I rushed in I saw nothing except for his furniture and a tiny circuit with some cells. I know he was a genius, what message could have he left for me?

The cells were marked with colors and their emfs:

They read as:

> 66V - BLUE - [Ideal Cell]
>
> 70V - BLACK - [Ideal Cell]
>
> 65V - VIOLET - [Ideal Cell]
>
> 83V- RED - [Ideal Cell]
>
> 72V - INDIGO - [Ideal Cell]
>
> 73V - GREEN - [Ideal Cell]
>
> 69V - YELLOW - [Ideal Cell]
>
> 77V - ORANGE - [Ideal Cell]

**Hint:**

> The value of current in the circuit corresponds to certain ASCII characters and the color in the resistors will help you arrange the characters to get the message.

Here's the circuit:[image: Circuit]

Comment: should this require knowledge tag as well?

Comment: @ben-NabiyDerush I am poor at tagging. Can you please add some tags that may seem relevant to you, I will edit the ones I feel irrelevant.

Comment: Are you sure about the colours, especially if the colours violet and indigo are used?

Comment: The only answer I find with the current knowledge is rot13(SVFU ORNZ), which, as funny as it might be, doesn't seem to be the answer

Comment: @Auribouros how did you find that answer? I mean, the letters are correct but what about the order?

Comment: @melfnt Brute-forcing, that is the only set of words that made "some" sense. There doesn't seem to be any logical sequence for the colors then. Having tried the colors in order of their resistor code, or rainbow order. So I did the second thing that came to mind, which might end up being incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I am on the right track, but:

> If you apply Ohm's law to the circuit with those cells, you arrive at I = the same as the voltage. If you apply those numbers to ASCII, you arrive at B,F,A,S,H,I,E,M. Possible anagram?

Regarding the colors:

> If done in accord with the rainbow, they spell SMEIBHAF assuming black is the last color. Something to do with "my behalf"?

Comment: I think you meant I (current) is the same, not R. R is defined as 1 ohm in the question

Comment: You haven't used the colors yet. They look important

Comment: ben you are quite on the right track and that is current not R. Also as @Techidiot pointed you still have the colors to use.

Comment: They look like color codes for Resistors..

Comment: I am not sure if the order is according to resistor color pattern, or if it is a modifier. If anyone else has ideas, throw them out there :)

Comment: @ben-NabiyDerush I added a hint.

Comment: Maybe someone else has an answer, I am not sure how else to interpret it.

Answer (score 1):

My best attempt so far...

Working from @ben-Nabiy Derush's answer, we know that the 8 letters are:

> B, F, A, S, H, I, E and M

Using the colours for the "order"

> If we assume the colours are ordered R-O-Y-G-B-I-V-L, then we can number each 1 - 8, which would give us the following sequence: 5-8-7-1-6-4-3-2
>
> Taking the 5th, 8th, 7th... etc letters gives us:
> H M E B I S A F
>
> So "home be safe" perhaps?

A few other things I noted:

> It's possible to make "IM SAFE" with the available letters, but that leaves 'H' and 'B' as the remaining letter. Somehow I don't think the solution is "HB IM SAFE" (Happy Birthday, I'm safe)
>
> If you use resistor colours (red = 2, orange = 3, yellow = 4, green = 5, blue = 6, violet = 7) and increment each letter we found by that number (so the first 'B' is blue (6), which becomes 'H') and if you leave black and indigo as they are (they're not resistor colours), it spells out:
> H F H U H N H P
> I don't think it's the answer, but I thought it was a neat conincidence